# Can you identify these ants?

Tags: species-identification, ant

I think they could be carpenter ants, but not sure. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Identifications questions should also include: 1) the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this organism; and 2) an estimate of the size of the organism. Please [edit] your post to include this essential information. ——— In addition, we don't provide advice about pest treatment (especially regarding safety), so I've deleted that part of your question. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 